# What does mean "run parallel to"?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

In the following sentence, what is the meaning of "runs parallel to"?

> The street where I live runs parallel to the main road through town.

Is it a phrasal verb? (I could not find it in any dictionary or internet resources!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[run](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/run)** (v): 4. Extend or cause to extend in a particular direction.  *cobbled streets run down to a tiny harbour*
>
> **[parallel](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/parallel)** (adj): 1. (of lines, planes, or surfaces) side by side and having the same distance continuously between them. *parallel lines never meet*

The combined meaning is that the roads "extend in a particular direction, with a parallel relationship to each other".

Answer (score 0):

streets are said to "run" east-west or north-south, for example. Run here just means "is".

Many things can be said to run in reference to the real world: the property line runs close to the street. [is close to].

The street where I live is parallel to x. Same thing as "runs parallel to".

Lines, streets, etc. **run in this or that direction** or are parallel or perpendicular to something.